# Run applications on different ports Apache and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, centos

I have an apache web server running. Serving an application located in /var/www/html/ (the application was built from React and is just a html linking some assets) when I access my website at the port 80 [www.mywebsite.com:80/](http://www.mywebsite.com:80/) It shows my application. What I want now is to run a second application in NodeJS on the server, at the port 3000 so when someone access my website at this port 3000 [www.website.com:3000/](http://www.website.com:3000/) Apache will redirect the user to my NodeJS application, basically what I want is to serve two applications on the server with different ports. I would like to know how to do that.

I tried do setup a reverse proxy but it didn't work I would like to know the detailed steps I have to take.

Comment: WHat did you try so far?